# How do I make a button inactive on radio button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-forms

I want to make a submit button inactive (not clickable) until one of form's radio buttons is checked.

This is what I have so far:

```
{% for answer in form.poll.answers.all %}
    <p class='field radio question'>
        <input id='{{ form.answer.auto_id }}_{{ answer.pk }}' type='radio' name='{{ form.answer.html_name }}' value='{{ answer.pk }}' />
        <label for='{{ form.answer.auto_id }}_{{ answer.pk }}'>
            <em>{{ answer }}</em>
        </label>
    </p>
{% endfor %}

<button class='buttons' type='submit' id='id_vote_button'>{% trans "Vote" %}</button>

<script src='{% static 'scripts/libs/jquery.js' %}'></script>

<script>
    $("input.radio").on('click', function () {
        console.log("click test");
        if ($('form.poll input.radio:checked')[0]) {
            console.log("true test");
            $("#id_vote_button").setAttribute('active', true);
        }
        else {
            console.log("false test");
            $("#id_vote_button").setAttribute('active', false);
        }
    });
</script>
```

The problem is the `$("input.radio").on('click', function ()` does not cause any effect in console when I click on radio buttons.

Comment: $(".radio input").on('click', function(){console.log(1)})... Try this... And let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `disabled` property of button which can achieved via using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method and use correct selector `:radio` to target the radio elements.

```
$(":radio").on('change', function () {
    $("#id_vote_button").prop('disabled', $('form.poll :radio:checked').length == 0);
});
```

I would recommend you to use `change` event instead of `click`

Note: there is no `setAttribute()` method defined in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not catch the 'click' event, but the 'change' event.

```
$("input.radio").on('change', function () {
...
}
```

or

```
$("input.radio").change(function () {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Satpals answer but changed it a bit to following using the `.is()` function provided by jQuery

```
$("input.radio").on('change', function () {
    $("#id_vote_button").prop('disabled', $('form.poll input.radio').is(':checked'));
});
```

or you could even use `$(this)`

```
$('input.radio').on('change', function () {
    $('#id_vote_button').prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```